# NodeJS TLS/TCP server in need of an external firewall

Tags: node.js, nginx, cloudflare, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-elb

**Problem:**
I have an AWS EC2 instance running FreeBSD. In there, I'm running a NodeJS TLS/TCP server. I'd like to create a set of rules (in my NodeJS application) to be able to individually block IP addresses programmatically based on a few logical conditions.

I'd like to run an external (not on the same machine/instance) firewall or load-balancer, that I can control from NodeJS programmatically, such that when certain conditions are given, I can block a specific remote-address(IP) before it reaches the NodeJS instance.

**Things I've tried:**
I have initially looked into *nginx* as an option, running it on a second instance, and placing my NodeJS server behind it, but after skimming through the *NGINX
Cookbook
Advanced Recipes for High Performance
Load Balancing* I've learned that only the NGINX Plus (the paid version) allows for remote/API control & customization. While I believe that paying $3500/license is not too much (considering all NGINX Plus' features), I simply can not afford to buy it at this point in time; in addition the only feature I'd be using (at this point) would be the *remote API control* and the *IP address blocking*.

My second thought was to go with the AWS/ELB (elastic-load-balancer) by integrating AWS' SDK into my project. That sounded feasible, unfortunately, after reading a few forum threads and part of their documentation (unless I'm mistaken) it seems these two features I need are not available on the AWS/ELB. AWS seems to offer an entire different service called WAF that I honestly don't understand very well (both as a service and from a feature-stand-point).

I have also (briefly) looked into CloudFlare, as it was recommended in one of the posts, here on Sackoverflow, though I can't really tell if their firewall would allow this level of (remote) control.

**Question:**
What are my options? What would you guys recommend I did?

Comment: Personally I'd go with what I know - strike that: with what I used to know - which is the efficient, simple and free `iptables` set of commands in *nix environments.
If the _external_ thing is necessary, you can surely cook up a small HTTP server listening only to your EC2, which would trigger `iptables`' operations. Or maintain some low-level socket-like communication between the two instances. (Disclaimer: I would not "recommend" this, it's just an idea that seems simple and robust.) (Addendum: +1 for this clean, complete post!)

Comment: @StockOverflaw, +1 on iptables. I have looked into using PF in a similar manner; though I think such setup would work for testing, I'd run into the same issue: would prefer to not host a dedicated firewall myself (on an instance) - if possible

Answer (score 1):

I think Nginx provide such kind of functionality please refer to [link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/amp/)
If you want to block an IP with Node TCP you can just edit a nginx config file and deny IP address.

Frankly speaking, If I were you, I would use AWS WAF but if you don’t want to use it, you can simply use Node JS

In Node JS You should have a global array variable where you will store all blocked IP addresses and upon connection, you will check whether connected host IP is in blocked IP variable. However there occurs a problem when machine or application is restarted, you will lose all information about blocked IP-s. So as a solution to that you can just setup [Redis](https://redis.io) (It is key-value database but there are also other datatypes) DB and store blocked IP-s there. Inasmuch as Redis DB is in RAM all interaction with DB will be instantly and as long as machine or node is restarted, Redis makes a backup on hard drive and it syncs from it and continue to work in RAM with old databases.

Comment: +1 for Redis recommendation; NGINX does not allow "remote-access"; the article shared shows how to set it up "locally"; please note that I'd prefer to keep the server and the firewall separated; +1 on the AWS WAF, have you ever worked with AWS WAF before? I can't find anywhere TCP blocking in the documentation

Comment: Yes, you are right if you want to block IP remotely NGINX is not an option.

Comment: AWS WAF is simple and very dynamic, you can specify your dynamic rules in order to block request or merely specify IP [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) it depends on your rules and it does not meter connection is TCP or HTTP, AWS WAF does not allow it. It is used only with AWS CloudFront or Elastic Load Balancing. Unfortunately, it is not free [link](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/pricing/).
It is easy to use [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl.html)

Comment: 1) You should create [Web ACLs](https://console.aws.amazon.com/waf/home?region=global#/wizard/webacl) (be carefull with region field)

Comment: In the documentation there is a line that tripped me: "web requests" - it does not specify "tcp requests" (http vs tcp); this is why I have disregarded it; furthermore, if you look at the API documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WAF.html#createByteMatchSet-property , specifically at the AWS.WAF object instantiation: "new AWS.WAF(options = {}) ⇒ Object" you'll notice that it only provides "httpOptions" not socket-based (TCP/UDP). Correct me if I'm wrong, but, requests that do not use the HTTP protocol can not be "filtered" by AWS.WAF.

Comment: mmm... I can't 100% sure say that it supports TCP. I used it with HTTP. You can test it, I will google AWS WAF supports TCP

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, so AWS.WAF doesn't really "fit the bill" - in this case

Comment: It is new for me. So, this issue is still not solved I will ask my colleagues what they would propose.

Comment: I assume there may be also one way with [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) but I don't know how to change Network ACL table programmatically using AWS JS SDK

Comment: than you for giving me a hand with this issue